# Якорь не работает как надо

Tags: html

Добрый день не работает якорь если заходить на сайт сразу с ним пример - site.ru/#skidka а если я нажимаю на  то все поднимается куда нужно. Подскажите в чем возможна проблема.

Comment: скорее всего проблема в `//` попробуй один убрать

Comment: @Grundy это я тут ошибся когда сообщение писал сори

Comment: Тогда проверь адрес, который вводишь и который становится после того как на ссылку жмешь.

Comment: @Grundy Одинаковые. Но работает все равно при клике на тэг только. Отключал Js думал может в нем проблема. Тоже результата ноль 
http://landing.alicom.dp.ua/#skidka

Comment: У тебя элемент с id=skidka - находится в самом верху страницы, в самом верху страница и появляется при переходе. При этом ссылка с якорем находится внизу страницы - вот и кажется что при ссылке переходит а при открытии сразу - нет

Answer (score 0):

Якорь вешается на **`id`** , например если перейти на твой сайт по ссылке:

> http://landing.alicom.dp.ua/#PrincipRaboti

То все прекрасно работает!:)

Comment: Попробуйте skidka :)

Comment: У тебя нет такого `id`. Посмотри внимательнее.

Comment: @Zicrael, есть же: `<div class="container" id="skidka">`

Comment: Почему у тебя секции нормально стоят а `skidka` это `div`? Сделай её так же как и секции и все решиться.